# Local node and remote node have different version numbers

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, ignite

I am trying to connect my spark client with ignite cluster version 2.5.0. When I run my spark submit job.

```
sudo /opt/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit --master k8s://https://35.192.214.68 --deploy-mode cluster --name sparkIgnite --class org.blk.igniteSparkResearch.ScalarSharedRDDExample --conf spark.executor.instances=3 --conf spark.app.name=sharedSparkIgnite --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=ignite --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=us.gcr.io/nlp-research-198620/ignite-spark:v2 local:///opt/spark/jars/igniteSpark-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

I  get the following error.

```
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to start manager: GridManagerAdapter [enabled=true, name=org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager

Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Local node and remote node have different version numbers (node will not join, Ignite does not support rolling updates, so versions must be exactly the same) [locBuildVer=2.5.0, rmtBuildVer=2.4.0, locNodeAddrs=[ignite-cluster-68787659f9-626k6/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, /10.8.2.82, /127.0.0.1], rmtNodeAddrs=[sparkignite-8bad224a0187324ba6f98da08e152c5e-driver/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, /10.8.2.87, /127.0.0.1], locNodeId=d0c82763-8931-4d66-89ad-2689d8b3d01a, rmtNodeId=b6383f55-ecc6-4d5f-acb2-4bd9970d3fc2]
```

The error says that my ignite cluster (local) is using 2.5.0 and my remote pod is using 2.4.0.  But the ignite I have contains 2.5.0 ignite image, so where is the 2.4.0 version coming from?

Pom

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.blk</groupId>
<artifactId>igniteSpark</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ignite-spark_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ignite-scalar_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
        <artifactId>ignite-kubernetes</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
</configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>org.blk.igniteSparkResearch.ScalarSharedRDDExample</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Docker Image

```
FROM spark:latest 
RUN mkdir -p /opt/spark/jars  
COPY target/igniteSpark-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar /opt/spark/jars
```

Here my spark image is build using Dockerfile which comes with spark-2.3.0

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From your log, I see that you have

1)ignite-cluster-68787659f9-626k6 with 2.5.0
2)sparkignite-8bad224a0187324ba6f98da08e152c5e-driver with version 2.4.0.

Could you please check that you have 2.5.0 ignite version in your spark configuration?

https://apacheignite-fs.readme.io/docs/installation-deployment

Comment: I have used 2.5.0 in my pom file and even my local system has 2.5.0. Is there a way where spark is still using 2.4.0?

Comment: Maybe you forgot to change the spark classpath and it looks to 2.4.0 libraries instead of 2.5.0? Could you please describe the steps how you deploy ignite and spark?

Comment: 1. Created ignite cluster on Google Kubernetes Engine with ignite version 2.5.0. Checked logs as well.

2. Created an image on my jar which I need to run which talks to ignite nodes created in the first step. After creating the image used spark submit command to run it on K8s cluster.

Comment: Step one is clear. I guess that the reason in step 2. Could you check that your image will use the correct version of Ignite libraries?

Comment: Since all my pom dependencies are in 2.5.0, I can't figure out why my spark is still using 2.4.0.

Comment: For running ignite as client mode, I use default spark image. Is there a way to check the ignite version on remote nodes?

Comment: Can you provide the link to this image? I think you should check it pom.xml.

Comment: Updated the post.  Can you check now?

Comment: I see that you add igniteSpark-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar. Could you please provide the information how you build/get it?

Comment: Also is it possible that you have some alive 2.4 nodes? Could you check what is running now using next command 'kubectl get pods -o yaml'